# "Enter" from keyboard on "Log-in" button doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, login

During the check-out logging-in procedure, pressing "Enter" from keyboard (after entering account details) does not log-in while it works if clicking with the mouse on the button.

What could be the problem?

Here the phtml :

```
<div class="col-2">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form id="login-form" action="/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="" />
            <h4>Already registered?</h4>
            <p>Please log in below:</p>
            <ul class="form-list ksm-login">
                <li>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="email">Email Address<em class="required">*</em></label>
                        <br />
                        <input name="login[username]" value="" id="email" class="input-text required-entry-email validate-email" title="Email Address" type="text">
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <label for="pass">Password<em class="required">*</em></label>
                        <br />
                        <input name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry-password validate-password" id="pass" title="Password" type="password">
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
        <button type="submit" class="button login" onclick="onepageLogin(this)"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>
        <a href="/customer/account/forgotpassword/" class="f-right">Forgot your password?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here the JavaScript :

```
var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
$('login-email').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
$('login-password').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
function bindLoginPost(evt){
    if (evt.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
        loginForm.submit();
    }
}
function onepageLogin(button)
{
    if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){
        button.disabled = true;
        loginForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the actions buttons inside the form, remove the onclick from the submit button and add an event listener for the form submit to run that function instead, something like this:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#login-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    onepageLogin(this);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter button doesn't work because "submit" outside of  tag. You may use this one solution:

```
<div class="col-2">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form id="login-form" action="/customer/account/loginPost/" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="" />
        <h4>Already registered?</h4>
        <p>Please log in below:</p>
        <ul class="form-list ksm-login">
            <li>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <label for="email">Email Address<em class="required">*</em></label>
                    <br />
                    <input name="login[username]" value="" id="email" class="input-text required-entry-email validate-email" title="Email Address" type="text">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <label for="pass">Password<em class="required">*</em></label>
                    <br />
                    <input name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry-password validate-password" id="pass" title="Password" type="password">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
    </fieldset>
<div class="buttons-set">
    <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
    <button type="submit" class="button login" onclick="onepageLogin(this)"><span><span>Login</span></span></button>
    <a href="/customer/account/forgotpassword/" class="f-right">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
</form>
```